# JW Player 6 controlbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

Have problem with JW player 6 controlbar. The matter is it always hides after some time and i need it to stay visible all the time. Are there any setup options for controlbar or built in methods or properties in jwplayer.js for this? Couldn't find it by myself.

Answer (score 1):

JW Player 6 indeed does not support displaying the controls at all times. Is there a specific use case for this? Given all HTML5 browsers do the same, this se

Comment: I would be happy with this if you could also hide the bug with the player controls.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `controlbar.position(bottom)` - Position of the controlbar. Can be set to bottom, top, over and none; or `controlbar.idlehide ( false )` to force it not to hide during play mode. This should work for embedded videos, check the full api list [here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12536/configuration-options#layout).

**EDIT** brief example:

```
"player": {
  "modes": {
     "linear": {
        "controls": { "manage": false }
     }
  }
},
```

You may wanna also check these [examples](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/open-video-ads/22834/configuring-the-control-bar/).

Comment: The full api list link you provided is for jwplayer v5. Are there differences between that and jwplayer 6?

Comment: Correct, so I've researched it and unfortunately: "The controlbar, dock and icons options are merged. In the revamped JW6 interface, all video controls show/hide in unison. Their placement and appearance are optimized for every player state. As a consequence, it is not possible anymore to show or hide individual parts of the controls. Instead, a single controls option is available to enable or disable all controls together." Check it here what is possible now - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28839/embedding-the-player

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack, and likely to be blown away by a core update, but I found a little heavy handed CSS got the job done for me.  Note, you'll have to adjust the positioning values for your particular deployment. You can just watch for the specific styles added to the elements by jwplayer when the controls appear.

```
#yourid_controlbar {
    display:inline-block !important;
    opacity:1 !important;
}

#yourid_controlbar .jwgroup.jwcenter {
    left:105px !important;
    right:100px !important;
}
```